# Is json.load inefficient?

Tags: python, json

I was looking at the source of the `json` module to try to answer another question when I found something curious. Removing the docstring and a whole bunch of keyword arguments, the source of `json.load` is as follows:

```
def load(fp):
    return loads(fp.read())
```

This was not at all as I expected. If `json.load` doesn't avoid the overhead of reading the whole file at once, is its only advantage over `json.loads(f.read())` the savings of a few characters of source code? Why does it even exist? Why does it get the short name, instead of `loads` getting the `load` name and `load` getting a name like `loadf`? I can think of reasons (copying the `pickle` interface, for example), but can anyone provide an authoritative answer rather than speculation?

Comment: I think your `pickle` idea is more than speculation. The `json` module documentation says, "`json` exposes an API familiar to users of the standard library `marshal` and `pickle` modules", which strongly suggests this is intentional. Of course it's possible there's another reason as well.

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient? The whole text *must* be read eventually, so doing a single `read` they are minimizing I/O time. Also, *if* the text of the file cannot stay into RAM, then almost surely the result wouldn't stay into RAM. Having all the text available avoids to deal with the issue during parsing, which might speed up the parsing significantly. If you want to send gigabytes of data around you shouldn't use `json` anyway, so I don't see how this choice is wrong.

Comment: @Bakuriu However if the string takes ~50% of memory and parsed object takes say ~75% of memory then `load` (implemented as above) will fail. On the other hand parsing a file chunk by chunk would work. So it is inefficient in terms of memory. It is a bit abstract though. Who's working with such big JSONs in the first place?

Comment: @freakish That's my point. If the string takes ~50% of the memory you shouldn't use `json` at all, but a more efficient encoding. In fact you shouldn't try to decode object that takes that big amount of RAM too, since a ~75% RAM-size object would make the computer swap a lot anyway.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I'm aware of that. It doesn't answer the question of why `json.load` exists or whether it "should" be used, though. I came up with a bunch of reasons why `load` might be implemented this way, but they're all speculative, and none of them answer the question of whether and how strongly I should prefer it to `loads(f.read())`.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm sure that the reason is compatibility with other libraries and that there's no other reason. But the question is not really that good. You ask "why does it exist?" and I can ask "why not?". Why does it bother you?

Comment: @freakish: It bothers me because I expected it to be better than `json.loads(f.read())`. The documentation focuses on `load`; since `loads(f.read())` is so obvious, it's natural to expect that `load` does *something* better.

Comment: To me, the only reasons `json.load` exists, is to allow loading JSON data from any object that implements the `file` API (i.e. the `read` method), and (as said by @SteveJessop) to expose an API similar to the others Python's serialization modules.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think you're trying to make a virtue of a necessity there. I'm pretty sure that `json.load` is simple for the sake of simplicity, not as an optimization. Since it's not the only JSON parser available, it doesn't need to be optimal and there's no need to dismiss as irrelevant the cases for which it's *seriously* non-optimal. In a lot of cases, compressed json is actually a pretty compact binary interchange format, you don't need to write it off as wholly inappropriate for large data.

Comment: ... that said, if you're transferring a giant amount of data by JSON then often in practice you'd come up with some kind of paging API anyway. So if each page is small-ish then the current implementation of `json.load` is not particularly harmful.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is natural to expect `json.load()` does something better, as mentioned in the comments, it doesn't guarantee to do so. This is purely speculative, but if I were a Python maintainer, I would design the modules for the simplicity and least maintenance overhead.

Python standard library `json` module is not optimal, in speed-wise or memory-usage wise. There are many alternative JSON reading implementations for different sweet spots and some of them have Python bindings e.g. [Jansson](https://github.com/demdxx/python-jansson):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512887/315168

Alternative JSON implementation are born from the necessity to handle streaming and/or huge amount of data in efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably safe to say that reading JSON from files, although important, is not the main use case for JSON serialization. Thus, implementing an efficient JSON load from file is not that interesting, except in special cases (there are more efficient ways of serializing huge data structures to disk).

However, generalizing the concept may introduce some useful aspects (JSON deserialization from network streams, for example, or progressive JSON deserialization from pipes).

What we are looking for then is a streaming parser (for example like SAX for XML). [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.io/yajl/) is a common such parser, and there are [some Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) for it

Also see the top answer to this question: [Is there a streaming API for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444380/is-there-a-streaming-api-for-json)

Comment: "implementing an efficient JSON load from file is not that interesting" -- it would be fun, though, if `read()` from a binary mode file could return a byte-sequence-like object that's just a copy-on-write wrapper for a read-only memory map of (part of) the file :-)

Comment: That would indeed be fun, though I suspect it would fail on string encoding. Data blobs are base64, regular strings are UTF-8, neither are very useful as is.