# C++ standard serialization

Tags: c++, serialization

My problem is serializing you see I saved files before but only one lined text file's I want more advanced files that have a out put like:

`[%File version format%]`

```
Player
{
Health:100
MP:17
    Transform
    {
    X:13.91,
    Y:15.36,
    Z:82.68
    Rx:14
    //......and so on
    }
    Inventory
   {
    Weapons(mace[dam:80%])
    Chemicals(liquid nitrogen, chemicals)
   }
}
```

I've tried so many times probley compiled my program over 31 times for just one thing, and also i will not like to use Json, xml ect.

Comment: or just post how one would do it here

Comment: there is no standard serialization for c++ , choose your poison. json is cool , google finds : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512650/fastest-json-reader-writer-for-c

Comment: Here's another link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's helpful to actually have a question for us to answer...what are you wanting to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Here's another, better link that offers more options. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/what-are-good-solutions-for-serialization-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Happy to hear you are giving c++ a try. For the example file you have, I would checkout YAML.

http://www.yaml.org/start.html

There are quite a few libraries that provide support for it if you don't want to write your own. Some resource to read up on include:

https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial

And the main page on the site hosts a variety of links to various libraries: http://yaml.org/

Comment: Please do not encourage off-topic questions by answering them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My apologies. Didn't think it was off-topic enough to matter. Would you like me to delete the answer?

Comment: i have a problem of use other peoples libarys simular to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here

Comment: @ChristopherLovell I understand that quite well. I actually share that philosophy in a lot of ways. However it still might give you a starting point to look at how you would go about doing it. I actually have written my own configuration system that I use quite frequently, but often times it can also be important to consider using known standards.

Comment: also ive hand writen over 38 files for mygames to read that use a formatt i was going to use for my game, formatt is my own

Comment: @ChristopherLovell Sounds nice, Id still suggest taking a look at how other people have solved it to see what you like/don't like; and then proceed to write your own library if you wish. Good luck with it :)

Comment: Ok Thanx i give them all a try and try my best to cope with using them